# how can I adapt a geometry to a surface?

Tags: three.js

How can I adapt a geometry (a box geometry to start with) to another one? I am looking for an effect like the one in the picture

[image]

where the cyan part was originally a box and then it got "adapted" to the plane and over the red part.

This is possible in some software packages (Modo, for example) but I'd like to do it in webGL/three.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider modifying mesh geometry.

That implies for good results mesh will need to have high polygon count.

If you want to hug a simple shape (box, sphere) - vertex displacement can be sufficient:

- Pass your red shape's parameters as uniforms when drawing blue shape
- For any blue shape vertex find if it is inside or red shape and offset vertex position if needed
- Choosing offset direction as closest face normal of red shape should be ok

That will give just visuals, if you need more robust solution - generate new geometry entirely on cpu on demand.
For example:

- Loop through all vertices and offset them, mark offseted vertices
- Additionally loop to relax hard edges

I suspect real algorithms from 3d modelling software are more complex.

Comment: Thanks! Any pointers to start researching on this? Unfortunately I don't even know what to google for...

Comment: Check `vertex displacement` in google. I'll try to find time to add example fiddle.